# Floodfill algorithm for area with seed point

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I have array of small areas defined by start xy and ending xy points, And i have seed xy point which lies somewhere in that area collectively. so my goal is to find all the areas which are linked to seed point. so any idea how to do it, i know for images we have floodfill algo in which we look for pixel color in all four directions. so is it possible something can be done for areas.

my js code

```js
let cblock = [
    // 3307 and 3306 touching
    {name: "#left_p3307", xs: 88.29, ys: 219.4, xe: 90.84, ye: 223.94},
    {name: "#p3306", xs: 87.87, ys: 219.83, xe: 91.27, ye: 223.51},
    // 3305 touch with 3307 and 3306
    {name: "#p3305", xs: 90.42, ys: 223.09, xe: 91.27, ye: 223.94},
    // 3304 touch with 3307 and 3306
    {name: "#p3304", xs: 90.42, ys: 219.4, xe: 91.27, ye: 220.25},
    // 3303 touch with 3307 and 3306
    {name: "#p3303", xs: 87.86, ys: 219.4, xe: 88.71, ye: 220.25},
    // 3302 touch with 3307 and 3306
    {name: "#p3302", xs: 87.86, ys: 223.09, xe: 88.71, ye: 223.94},
    // center no touch with any coordinates
    {name: "#center", xs: 93.68, ys: 221.1, xe: 95.09, ye: 222.24},
    
    {name: "#right_p3301", xs: 97.93, ys: 219.4, xe: 100.48, ye: 223.94},
    {name: "#p3300", xs: 97.5, ys: 219.83, xe: 100.91, ye: 223.51},
    {name: "#p3299", xs: 100.05, ys: 223.09, xe: 100.91, ye: 223.94},
    {name: "#p3298", xs: 100.05, ys: 219.4, xe: 100.91, ye: 220.25},
    {name: "#p3297", xs: 97.5, ys: 219.4, xe: 98.35, ye: 220.25},
    {name: "#p3296", xs: 97.5, ys: 223.09, xe: 98.35, ye: 223.94}
];


// seed xy
let seed_x = 90;
let seed_y = 222;

// possible 4 direction
let dx = [0, -1, +1, 0];
let dy = [-1, 0, 0, +1];

let storage = [];

// loop on coordinates
for (let i in cblock) {
    
    let cord = cblock[i];
    // check if touching seed point
    if( (seed_x >= cord.xs && seed_x <= cord.xe) && (seed_y >= cord.ys && seed_y <= cord.ye) ){
        storage.push(cord);
    }
    
    //console.log(cblock[i]);
} 

// output points touching seed
console.log(storage);
```

so with xy seeds like **[90,222]** i should have coordinates of range **#p3302** to **#left_p3307** like

```js
storage = [
    {name: "#left_p3307", xs: 88.29, ys: 219.4, xe: 90.84, ye: 223.94},
    {name: "#p3306", xs: 87.87, ys: 219.83, xe: 91.27, ye: 223.51},
    {name: "#p3305", xs: 90.42, ys: 223.09, xe: 91.27, ye: 223.94},
    {name: "#p3304", xs: 90.42, ys: 219.4, xe: 91.27, ye: 220.25},
    {name: "#p3303", xs: 87.86, ys: 219.4, xe: 88.71, ye: 220.25},
    {name: "#p3302", xs: 87.86, ys: 223.09, xe: 88.71, ye: 223.94}
];
```

and for seed point like **[93,221]** i should only have **#center** area
like

```js
storage = [
{name: "#center", xs: 93.68, ys: 221.1, xe: 95.09, ye: 222.24}
];
```

and for seed point like **[100,222]** i should only have right block
like

```js
storage = [
   {name: "#right_p3301", xs: 97.93, ys: 219.4, xe: 100.48, ye: 223.94},
    {name: "#p3300", xs: 97.5, ys: 219.83, xe: 100.91, ye: 223.51},
    {name: "#p3299", xs: 100.05, ys: 223.09, xe: 100.91, ye: 223.94},
    {name: "#p3298", xs: 100.05, ys: 219.4, xe: 100.91, ye: 220.25},
    {name: "#p3297", xs: 97.5, ys: 219.4, xe: 98.35, ye: 220.25},
    {name: "#p3296", xs: 97.5, ys: 223.09, xe: 98.35, ye: 223.94}
];
```

Comment: Can you be more explicit about the expected output format for the two examples?

Comment: @trincot output is just to group them and push them as a match group , i have added sample format in question . thanks

Comment: What is the relevance of `cblock_width` and `cblock_height`?

Comment: @trincot removed it , as it was just max X and max Y

Comment: @trincot have added sample svg , these coordinates are actually from svg file and i was hopping to lock on its paths on left right in separate groups using some technique like flood fill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a graph problem, where the areas are the nodes, and edges exist when areas overlap. Once the seed point has been mapped to area(s) that contain it, it is a matter of following the edges of the graph to find all linked areas.

Here is an implementation:

```js
  function overlaps(areaA, areaB) {
    return areaA.xs <= areaB.xe && areaB.xs <= areaA.xe &&  
           areaA.ys <= areaB.ye && areaB.ys <= areaA.ye;     
}

function includes(area, x, y) {
    return area.xs <= x && x <= area.xe &&
           area.ys <= y && y <= area.ye;
}

function createGraph(cblock) {
    let graph = new Map(cblock.map(area => [area, []]));
    for (let areaA of cblock) {
        let adjacent = graph.get(areaA);
        for (let areaB of cblock) {
            if (areaA !== areaB && overlaps(areaA, areaB)) adjacent.push(areaB);
        }
    }
    return graph;
}

function findConnectedAreas(cblock, seedX, seedY) {
    let graph = createGraph(cblock);
    let areas = new Set(cblock.filter(area => includes(area, seedX, seedY)));
    for (let area of areas) {
        for (let adjacent of graph.get(area)) areas.add(adjacent);
    }
    return Array.from(areas);
}

// Example run
let cblock = [
    {name: "#left_p3307", xs: 88.29, ys: 219.4, xe: 90.84, ye: 223.94},
    {name: "#p3306", xs: 87.87, ys: 219.83, xe: 91.27, ye: 223.51},
    {name: "#p3305", xs: 90.42, ys: 223.09, xe: 91.27, ye: 223.94},
    {name: "#p3304", xs: 90.42, ys: 219.4, xe: 91.27, ye: 220.25},
    {name: "#p3303", xs: 87.86, ys: 219.4, xe: 88.71, ye: 220.25},
    {name: "#p3302", xs: 87.86, ys: 223.09, xe: 88.71, ye: 223.94},
    {name: "#center", xs: 93.68, ys: 221.1, xe: 95.09, ye: 222.24},    
    {name: "#right_p3301", xs: 97.93, ys: 219.4, xe: 100.48, ye: 223.94},
    {name: "#p3300", xs: 97.5, ys: 219.83, xe: 100.91, ye: 223.51},
    {name: "#p3299", xs: 100.05, ys: 223.09, xe: 100.91, ye: 223.94},
    {name: "#p3298", xs: 100.05, ys: 219.4, xe: 100.91, ye: 220.25},
    {name: "#p3297", xs: 97.5, ys: 219.4, xe: 98.35, ye: 220.25},
    {name: "#p3296", xs: 97.5, ys: 223.09, xe: 98.35, ye: 223.94}
];
let seedX = 90;
let seedY = 222;
let result = findConnectedAreas(cblock, seedX, seedY);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: nice just one problem not returning result for single hit like : 93,221 . thanks

Comment: OK, will check that...

Comment: 93 is not in the center, since the center has a minimum x coordinate that is greater than 93 (it is 93.68). Is the seed not a single point?

Comment: ya you right :)